# ODBC connection to SQL Server 2008 through VPN failing

Tags: sql-server, excel, odbc, vpn

I have an Excel add-in that allows users to run queries against a SQL Server database and return the results directly to the spreadsheet. This works fine.

There is now a user in a satellite office who is connecting to our network (shared drive, etc.) through a VPN connection. When he uses the same spreadsheets that work for everyone in the main office, her gets the following error:

*[DBNETLIB] SQL Server does not exist or access denied*

What is really strange is that if you run an individual query, it works fine, but it seems like running many queries in succession makes the sheet crap out. It's a little difficult to diagnose as the Excel add-in runs queries internally, possibly many of those. My theory is that when the DB server sees many successive queries come in from an IP that's outside of the network, there's a point at which it refuses to return more data.

Is there any validity to my theory?
Are there configuration changes I can make to the DB that will allow remote ODBC connections to work well?

Comment: In case you are interested, the issue is that I was creating a server-side cursor, and the queries would always time out as you have to pay the network round-trip for each cell in the result set. It started working fine when I switched to a client-side cursor. This is all using ADO. I am in the process of switching to SQLApi++.

Comment: Could you change this to the answer, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are interested, the issue is that I was creating a server-side cursor, and the queries would always time out as you have to pay the network round-trip for each cell in the result set. It started working fine when I switched to a client-side cursor. This is all using ADO. I am in the process of switching to SQLApi++